# Saving SAS programs in XML format

Tags: xml, sas

A client wants a SAS program sent to them in `XML` format. Is this possible?

My only experience with XML files are as data files, converting `.xpt` to `.xml` for example.

Has anyone come across converting `.sas` to `.xml`?

Comment: Are they by chance using SAS Studio and looking to create TASK templates instead?

Comment: As asked this question doesn't have enough information to meaningfully answer.  XML is not really a format so much as a specification; you will need to explain the details of the specific XML schema that your client wants to follow and/or the tool or other relevant information for determining that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS programs are plain text files. Changing the extension to txt  or treating it as a text file from many applications may solve your problem.

You could create a program to save as XML but it would be the XML definition and a single field that contained the text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<program>
 SAS PROGRAM
 </program>
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently simply changing the extension will do it. XML format is to make a file machine readable, the text inside remains the same unless it's a data file which you want to open in internet explorer.

Comment: Changing the extension does not change the format of the file. You could change the extension to .xls and that would not make it an excel file. It's still just a text file with SAS code in it. I would ask your client why they want an xml file of SAS code. This could be done, but if you submitted the program to SAS with all the xml tags, it would error.

Comment: I suggest you send the client a short example program with a few trivial data steps, procs and macros and ask them what sort of xml representation they would expect for it, and whether there is a specific tool they would expect you to use to produce it.